# dotnet publish with .net core - How to work around relative paths not been honored in CopyToPublishDirectory?

Tags: .net-core

Building a .net core app on mac after migrating an old project.json to csproj.

None of the additional files/directories to be copied are being copied as part of the publish.  Seems to be because I am using relative paths, so wondering how to work around it and still use relative paths.

Basically, the migrated new element is as the following, and none of the files/directories are copied:

```
<None Update="..\wwwroot\**\*;..\foo1.config;..\;..\foo5.config;..\foo6.sh;">
  <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</None>
```